# Passing interfaces instead of concrete classes into @ChildContent's [CascadingParameter] using <CascadingValue> in blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, interface, refactoring, blazor

I have `Item` implementing `IItem`, and `ItemContainer` implementing `IItemContainer`.

In `ItemContainer.razor` I have the following, passing itself to all its `@ChildContent`:

```
<CascadingValue Value="this">
    @ChildContent
</CascadingValue>

@code{
  List<IItem> Items;
  void AddItem(IItem item) => Items.Add(item);
  .
  .
  .
}
```

And in the `Item` class I have the following:

```
[CascadingParameter] public IItemContainer ItemContainer {get;set;}
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
  ItemContainer.AddItem(this);
}
RenderFragment RenderStuff => Do some rendering stuff with ItemContainer
.
.
.
```

Say that I have the following:

```
<ItemContainer>
  <Item>
  <Item>
  <Item>
</ItemContainer>
```

I expect that by the time the first `<Item>` calls its `OnInitialized`,
the `<ItemContainer>` would already have passed itself into `[CascadingParameter] public IItemContainer ItemContainer {get;set;}`,
so `[CascadingParameter] public IItemContainer ItemContainer {get;set;}` will not be null,
and `ItemContainer.AddItem(this);` will be successfully called and add the `<Item>` to the `<ItemContainer>`'s `List<IItem> Items`.

This is not an issue if I use concrete classes, i.e. ItemContainer instead of IItemContainer for `<CascadingValue Value="this">`.

However, when the `this` of `<CascadingValue Value="this">` is an interface and not an concrete class, casting does not automatically happen, and null exception will be thrown (ItemContainer not passed into the cascading param).

And when I try to cast it using `<CascadingValue TValue="IItemContainer" Value="(IItemContainer)this">`, exception will be thrown.

I want to pass interfaces instead of concrete classes into cascading params. Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And when I try to cast it using

```
<CascadingValue TValue="IItemContainer" 
  Value="(IItemContainer)this">
```

> exception will be thrown.

You don't do that like this. You still have to pass `this`

Here's the way to do that:

### ItemContainer.razor

```
<CascadingValue Value="this">
    @ChildContent
</CascadingValue>

@code{
  List<IItem> Items;
  void AddItem(IItem item) => Items.Add(item);
  .
  .
  .
}
```

### Item.razor

```
@implements IItem
 
[CascadingParameter] public IItemContainer ItemContainer {get;set;}

protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    // Note: The first ItemContainer (left to right) is the class name,
    // the second is the name of the cascading parameter property. If the compiler
    // fail to recognize that (I guess she won't), change this property to 
    // ContainerItemSet, as for instance. Otherwise, it should work perfectly 
    // fine. 
    ((ItemContainer)(object)(ItemContainer)).AddItem(this);
}
```